# What is $ \lim u_n$ knowing that $\lim( -\frac{u_n}{n}) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

$0 < u_n < 1$

$(u_n)_n$ is decreasing and converge.

We also have $\lim( -\frac{u_n}{n}) = 0 $

What is $\lim u_n$?

I don't see how to use the fact that $\lim( -\frac{u_n}{n}) = 0 $ to find find $\lim u_n$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at a few examples., What if $u_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$?  Will $\lim (-\frac{u_n}{n})=0$?  What is $\lim u_n$ in this case?  What about if $u_n = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n+1}$?  Will $\lim(-\frac{u_n}{n})=0$?  What is $\lim u_n$ in this case?  Since these are both different and both possible, given only the information in your problem statement, does that mean you can uniquely find $\lim u_n$?

Comment: As an aside... *every* bounded sequence $b_n$ will have the property that $\lim \frac{b_n}{n}=0$, so being told that $\lim(-\frac{u_n}{n})$ hardly tells us anything about the nature of $u_n$.

Comment: $-u_n/n \leqslant  u_n^2 /2+1/2n^2$...then reverse the inequality and use the fact that $0<u_n<1$..